# KML Coordinates for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to make an app so the user will be able to click on a link(The links are locations) and it will open up google maps and direct them to the location. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ECC</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs |filter : search ">{{site.name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.SiteLocs = [
   {
  "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
  }

}
   , 
   {
  "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
  }
}, (ect... there are a couple thousand of these so I wont add them all..)
];
});
```

What I need help with is the linking its self. I dont know what to link the list to using href. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so what's your problem?  You didn't really ask a question.  Is your code not working?  Or do you not know how to achieve what you want?  No one is going to give you the complete code to do what you ask, but they will be happy to help you fix the problems you are having,

Comment: Sorry for being vague. When I put <a href="#/ect...."></a> into the code I do not know what to link it to in order to get it to google maps.

Comment: Then edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got it figured out. It was really simple.

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" border="1"/>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs |filter : search "><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=" + 
      {{site.Point.coordinates}}>{{site.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```